# ERM Address Types

Tags: database

I created the following ERM for saving addresses:

[image]
I wonder if the MANY to MANY relationship is correct between Addresses and Adresstypes? So my thinking is as follows:

- An Address can have multiple address types (e.g. POI, Private, Business)
- An Address Type can be associated with multiple addresses.

Is the setup like shown below right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined `address_id` as PK in both `Addresses` and `AddressTypes`. That automatically makes it a 1:1 relationship. You need an intersection between the two to map addresses to types, and I don't think you want to use `address_id` to do it. You want an intersection entity between `Address.address_id` and `AddressType.address_type_id`.

Comment: I agree, but address_id is the PK that will be the reference for FKs in different tables. Therefore I need it

Comment: But not in AddressTypes. I think I see what you're trying to do, and if I'm right you want an intersection entity between `Address.address_id` and `AddressType.address_type_id`.

Comment: yes. that is exactly right. I didn't show the table for that, because I thought the relationship arrow would imply that. Should these pivot tables be displayed in these diagrams?

Comment: That looks good. I may have been a bit AR about the two PKs having the same name; there doesn't seem to be a standard for that sort of thing in ERDs.

Comment: But is the logic for these AddressType correct, that it needs to be MANY to MANY? or is it ONE to MANY?

Comment: No, that's right, if an address can be of more than one type. *That* depends on your requirements.